# UIPageControllerDelegate Order of Operations Backwards?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

For a UIPageViewController and its delegation, is this the correct order of operations or should the last step be first?

```
willTransition
didFinishAnimating
viewControllerAfter/Before
```

`willTransition`’s definition says `Called before a gesture-driven transition begins.`

so that seems correct that it’s the first step to me, but I saw another answer on here that says `after/before` should be first

Answer (score 0):

`viewControllerAfter` and `viewControllerBefore` can be called at *any* time, because the page view controller tries to cache the adjacent view controllers before the user ever navigates to them. Therefore you should make no assumptions about order. Just answer the question that the delegate message asks, whenever it arrives. You should always be able to do that, because you are given a current view controller and you should be able to calculate the next or previous view controller from that. If your code thinks it needs to make assumptions about order, that's a Bad Smell and you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Can you expand on this "Just answer the question that the delegate message asks, whenever it arrives." a little more please

Comment: No, I really can't. I've said what I believe answers your question, and I believe I've said it quite clearly. There is "correct order of operations" with regard to `viewControllerAfter` and `viewControllerBefore`. The system calls your methods when it calls them. The end.